# Qual a melhor maneira de converter um projeto HTML5 em JSP?

Tags: html5, jsp

Boa tarde programadores, sou novo aqui no Stack e novo também nesse mundo tecnológico e mais ainda na área de programação.

Tenho um projeto de faculdade e como o primeiro bom projeto mesmo que em grupo existem dificuldades, e nossa maior foi de não perguntar e tirar duvidas com os professores. Foi ai que fizemos um projeto em HTML5 e na verdade era para estar em JSP e agora preciso converter todo para o mesmo. Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa mudança de HTML5 para JSP que seja menos trabalhoso possível?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O problema que você tem ai é que as páginas JSP são página geridas pelo servidor e as páginas em HTML5 são front end. Acho que o trabalho não vai ser evitado no seu caso. (opinião pessoal)

Comment: Foi a mesma coisa que pensei, só achei que teria alguma forma de minimizar meu sofrimento rsrs.

Comment: O JSP é apenas uma espécie de processamento de texto. Ele vai imprimir texto em cima de um layout qualquer, usando dados que estão no servidor. Não há problema algum esse layout ser um HTML, ou mesmo um TXT. Sem saber o que você usou como processamento na parte HTML fica complicado falar qualquer coisa a respeito.

Comment: Vou te falar a verdade, não entendo muito do assunto, quando você diz "o que você usou como processamento na parte HTML", quer dizer em qual programa foi escrito o código??